# How to save an Imagick converted image from pdf into a variable

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

How can I save a converted image file from pdf to jpg from local directory  into a variable? Does it have any function  that give such detail like  $_FILES when we upload file in php?

```
$target_dir="$media_dir/";
$target_file= $target_dir .  basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_file);
$image= new imagick();
$image->readImage($target_file);
$image->setImageFormat('jpg');

$imgname= basename($target_file,".pdf");

//converting pdf to jpg image and saving in local directory

foreach($imagick as $i=>$imagick) 
{ 
  $image->writeImage($target_dir . $imgname . ($i+1) ." of ". ".jpg"); 
} 

$image->clear();
```

Comment: Sorry, I am confused on the real question, as the title asks about saving into a variable? Or saving a pdf after conversion in a variable? Or getting file details from the variable of what you just saved? Or a mixture of any of the above? Could you please clarify a bit more on what you actually tried that is failing, and the real result you are looking for.

Comment: right now it convert the pdf image into jpg and saved in local directory. but i need to save the copy of converted jpg image into a variable ,right after conversion. actually i want to insert the converted jpg image into database as well.

Comment: You could use fopen/fread/fclose set of functions for that, so you know you are pulling the actual data that was saved. Then you will have the full binary in a variable to use for how you wish.

Comment: Or, just try to use the image blob: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimageblob.php

Comment: could you please give me example with reference to my code. pretty new to php and kind of difficult to do it

Comment: I could, but I'm a bit unclear why you are doing a foreach loop on the imagick object to save one image? And $pages isn't defined in your snippet, so uncertain where that came from or its importance in the loop.

Comment: i am using  foreach loop since pdf can be more than one page. so with that forloop i am converting each pdf page into saperate jpg image. just deleted $pages.. it wasn't part of it . eg if pdf file contain 2 page with name print.pdf then converted jpg image will be print 1 of .jpg and print 2 of .jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be helpful to start with:

For saving the file, try instead to use file_put_contents (writeImage can be flakey).

Then to use THAT converted image (from the loop) in variables and saving to database, you can get its full blob into an array to use after you are done saving/clearing.

```
$imageblobs = array();
foreach( ... ) {
    file_put_contents($target_dir . $imgname . ($i+1) .'_of_'. $page .'.jpg', $image);
    // $image is the Imagick object for the image you are saving

    $imageblobs[] = $image->getImageBlob();
    // OR you can skip putting it into an array, and just save direct to db right here
}

// now you can use each 'blob' variable you setup before you cleared it
foreach($imageblobs as $imageblob) {
    // save $imageblob to db blob column
    // or do other things with it
}
```

Note if you have a ton of images, and they are large, this can eat up php memory, so make sure you have some checks to prevent overrun.